# vba iterate over columns with formulas and filldown

Tags: excel, vba

I have a datasheet that is imported regularly and the length changes.

So, I want to write some VBA code that deletes any extra rows and autofills any formulas to the last row.

I have the first part done. This code finds the last row, and deletes anything below it.

```
Sub CleanData()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Sheets("Open Operations").Select
    Range(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1), _
      Cells(Rows.Count, 1)).EntireRow.Delete
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

End Sub
```

The part I'm stuck on is that I'm not sure how to autofill any columns that need it. These columns could be changing, so I want my code to be able to handle this. So, I want to iterate over all of the cells in the first row, from the very first column to the last column in use. Then, if that cell is a formula, I want to fill the formula down to the lastrow, as defined in the first code block.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Dim lastcolumn As Long

lastcolumn = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & lastcolumn).Cells

    If c.HasFormula = True Then
```

But I'm pretty new to VBA, and I'm not sure how to make the column fill down to the previously defined Last Row.

EDIT: To clarify -- I want to iterate over every first cell in each column until the last column. Then, if that cell contains a formula, I want to autofill/filldown that whole column to the lastrow defined in the first code block.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to create code that accomplishes the task mentioned above:

Here is the code for anyone interested:

```
Sub CleanData()

' Clean the data
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    Call CleanSheet("Order Headers")
    Call CleanSheet("Open Operations")
    Call CleanSheet("Confirmations (SAP)")
    Call CleanSheet("VA05")
    Call CleanSheet("ZOOP")
    Call CleanSheet("PremExped")

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic


End Sub

Sub CleanSheet(SheetName As String)

' Cleans the Sheet specified by SheetName

    ' Variable Declaration
    Dim NumColumns As Long
    Dim NumRows As Long
    Dim ColumnCounter As Long

    ' Find the number of rows and columns in SheetName
    NumRows = Sheets(SheetName).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    NumColumns = Sheets(SheetName.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    ' Define the ranges for pulling down the formulas
    Set rng1 = Worksheets(SheetName).Range("A2:A" & NumRows)
    Set rng2 = Worksheets(SheetName).Range("A2")

    ' Delete extraneous rows of data
    Sheets(SheetName).Select
    Range(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1), _
      Cells(Rows.Count, 1)).EntireRow.Delete

    ' Ensure all formulas are dragged down appropriately
    For ColumnCounter = 0 To NumColumns
        If rng2.Offset(0, ColumnCounter).HasFormula = True Then
        rng1.Offset(0, ColumnCounter).FillDown
        End If
        Next ColumnCounter

End Sub
```

Comment: Quick suggestion. Change this `Sub CleanSheet()` to `Sub CleanSheet(SheetName as String)`. Then you can remove all your `SheetName` references in clean data and change your call from this: `Call CleanSheet` to `Call CleanSheet("Order Headers")`, etc. This prevents multiple changes to the same variable in one procedure and cleans things up a bit.

Comment: @guitarthrower, thanks for the suggestion. I'm still pretty new to VBA. Do I need to declare the variable SheetName earlier in the code, or is the declaration in the Sub title sufficient?

Comment: Good question. Because it's declared as part of `CleanSheet` there is no need to declare it in `CleanData`. It becomes an argument of `CleanSheet` like how a range is an argument you give to a `SUM` formula on the worksheet.

Comment: Thanks. Changes made.

Comment: Looks great. You should accept your answer so that others who are looking for similar issues know that the code you posted worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

`("A1:A" & lColumn)` seems to confuse rows and columns.
I think you want:

```
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
or
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
```

EDIT: Maybe just the following:

```
For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
```

Comment: I actually think that part is right. I'm figuring out what the last column is. Then, for each of those columns, if the column contains a formula, I want to ensure the formula is extended down to the last row (as defined by xlong in the first code block).

Comment: @Austin Wismer - I had an afterthought - see EDIT